# Is there a way to specify the decoder in ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, ffprobe, transcoding

I am using ffprobe to extract information from a video file using following command on AWS VT1 that has hardware accelerated decoders available

> ffprobe -of json -show_streams -show_frames -show_format -i video.mp4

The above command still performs decoding using CPU.

I know that in case of ffmpeg, I can specify the decoder like this

> ffmpeg -c:v mpsoc_vcu_h264 -i video.mp4 -f null -

I was wondering if it is possible to specify a decoder to ffprobe as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked those that should know, and they say ffprobe has to do a **full decode** for this analysis (AVFrames can't be gotten otherwise), and there is **no way** to choose the codec, or to use hardware acceleration.

I was recommended to look into the `trace_headers` BSF and given this command:

`ffmpeg -v verbose -i input -map 0:v -c copy -bsf:v trace_headers -frames:v 5 -f null pipe:`

That dumps info in encoded form. Example: `pic_width_in_mbs_minus1` = 239 which indicates 240 * 16 = 3840 pixels width for the file I used to test this.

Comment: I believe that -show_frames requires decoding as mentioned in this thread https://ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.narkive.com/VxiRKpIy/ffprobe-documentation-seems-mixed-up-with-ffmpeg-docs#post5

Comment: If I am reading this code in ffprobe.c correctly then the assertion that decoding is happening seems correct.  https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffprobe.c#L2700

Comment: I would not be surprised if that AVFrame object didn't actually contain decoded picture data. I'm not set up to build and debug that though. -- I looked and didn't see any way to specify a decoder to ffprobe. I haven't been able to chase down those `dec_ctx` exactly.

Comment: ok I've revised my answer entirely, after talking to someone who has very extensive knowledge of the innards of ffmpeg.

Comment: I was working on a patch to choose decoders in ffmpeg. Will resume in due course.

Comment: you must mean ffprobe. ffmpeg can do it, but ffprobe can't. unless you mean ffmpeg...

Comment: Yes, sorry. ffprobe.